# Want to insert a text in a file beforealine using lineinfile in ansible playbook

Tags: shell, ansible, devops, ansible-template

I need to add a text before the end of a parameter in file. I need to insert my text just before `</abc>`. I am using lineinfile and it enters the text before `<abc>` and not `</abc>`.

My current text file :

> ```
> <domain-log-broadcast-filter>MultiDataSourceLogFilter</domain-log-broadcast-filter>
>       <abc>Info is already here. i just need to append the text at end of this parameter. new values to be inserted here</abc>
> ```

My Playbook :

```
  - lineinfile:
         path: /tmp/tochange.xml
         insertbefore:  '\<\/abc\>'
         line: "Tisisthelinetobeinsertedbyme"
         state: present
```

My Output for this is :

> ```
> <domain-log-broadcast-filter>MultiDataSourceLogFilter</domain-log-broadcast-filter>
> Thisisthelinetobeinsertedbyme
>       <abc>Info is already here. i just need to append the text at end of this parameter. new values to be inserted here</abc>
> ```

Now i have 2 requirements :

1. I want to insert my text just before `</abc>`
2. I have 4 `</abc>` parameters in my file. I want to ignore the first `</abc>` and the line is to be inserted before other 3 `</abc>` parameters.

Please sugest me a best way to do it, all i need is this work to be done, with any modules any script in the playbook. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"... with any modules any script in the playbook."*

A: [Ansible file modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_files_modules.html#files-modules) are not able to do it. You'll need the module *command* or *shell* to run file editing tools like *sed* or *awk*.

Module [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#lineinfile-manage-lines-in-text-files) is not able not to fulfill the requirements. This module modifies single lines in a file. It's not possible to change 3 out of 4 lines that match *regexp*. Neither [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html#replace-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) nor [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html#blockinfile-insert-update-remove-a-text-block-surrounded-by-marker-lines) modules will help you either, I'm afraid. The module [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#template-template-a-file-out-to-a-remote-server) modifies whole files. The next option might be the module [patch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/patch_module.html#patch-apply-patch-files-using-the-gnu-patch-tool).

Quoting from [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#synopsis):

> "... For other cases, see the copy or template modules."

Comment: Can you help me out with any module or shell which can do the job